# Relay fetchQuery: cache response

Tags: reactjs, relay

Is there a way to cached the data returned by `fetchQuery`?

For example:

```
fetchQuery(
          RelayEnviroment,
          Query,
          where: { name: { contains: "test" } }
        ).subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            resolve(data);
          },
        });
```

I expected that, if I already made this request with "test" params, the next time I do it it will be on cache.